# Quarkus Azure Functions Deployment

Tags: azure-functions, quarkus

i have been testing out Service Bus triggers, and HTTP triggers with Quarkus 2 and Quarkus 3 releases.

Locally there weren't any problems with both versions, but when i deployed my function to Azure (i am using Azure Pipelines), with Quarkus 2, everything is ok, but when i used Quarkus 3, i couldn't actually trigger (execute) the function, since for every trigger i made, i kept getting ClassNotFoundException. Note that only thing that was changed is only the version of Quarkus, nothing else in code and project itself. Deploy is indeed successful, and i can see in portal both my function and its associated files, but when it comes to execution of Function it fails.

Has anyone tried deployment of Azure Functions with Quarkus 3 on Azure Portal? Does anyone maybe have any idea or solution for this?